# How to find all directories which include sources?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a project with few directories (not all of them known in advance). I want to issue a command to find all directories which include sources. Something like `find . -name "*.cpp"` this will give me a list of sources while I want just a list of directories which include them. The project structure is not know in advance, some sources may exist in directory X and others in a sub directory X/Y. What will be the command which will print the list of all directories which include sources?

Comment: As an aside: It's nice to see that you took the time to respond to everyone who answered.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is that project? Do you want a generic solution? Why can't you use the project source version control repository? Please edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u
```

If (a) you have GNU `find` or a recent version of BSD `find` and (b) you have a recent version of `dirname` (such as GNU coreutils 8.21 or FreeBSD 10 but *not* OSX 10.10), then, for greater efficiency, use (Hat tip: Jochen and mklement0):

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -exec dirname {} + | sort -u
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that myself? :)

If you have GNU find, you can easily save calls to `dirname`by using + instead if ;

`find . -name \*.cpp -exec dirname '{}' + | sort -u`

Comment: @Jochen Thanks!  Also, interesting suggestion.  What  `dirname` are you using that handles multiple arguments?  Mine (debian stable) doesn't.

Comment: @John1024: the  `(GNU coreutils) 8.13` version of `dirname` (e.g., on Debian 3.2) does _not_ support multiple arguments, but `(GNU coreutils) 8.21` (e.g., on Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 20) _does_. Similarly, in the BSD world, the OSX 10.10 version does _not_ support multiple arguments, whereas the FreeBSD 10 version _does_.

Comment: @mklement0 and Jochen, thanks!  Answer updated with the `+` option and the version information.

Comment: My pleasure, @John1024. I think that only the `dirname` version is the variable here, not also the `find` version, given that ending `-exec` with `+` is a [POSIX-compliant feature](http://man.cx/find).

Answer (score 3):

[John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29569904/45375) is **elegant** and **fast**, **IF your version of `dirname` supports *multiple* arguments** and you can invoke it with `-exec dirname {} +`.

Otherwise, with `-exec dirname {} \;`, a child process is forked for each and every input filename, which is quite slow.

If:

- your `dirname` doesn't support multiple arguments
- and performance matters
- and you're using bash `4` or higher

consider the following solution:

```
shopt -s globstar; printf '%s\n' ./**/*.cpp | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u
```

- `shopt -s globstar` activates support for cross-directory pathname expansion (globbing)
- `./**/**.cpp` then matches `.cpp` files anywhere in the current directory's *subtree*

  - Note that the glob intentionally starts with `./`, so that the `sed` command below also properly reports the top-level directory *itself*, should it contain matching files.
- `sed 's|/[^/]*$||'` effectively performs the same operation as `dirname`, but on *all* input lines with a *single* invocation of `sed`.
- `sort -u` sorts the result and outputs only unique directory names.

Comment: Globstar is an under-used feature: + 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | while read f; do dirname "$f" ; done | sort -u
```

should do what you need

Comment: You got it right but @John1024 wrote a shorter and cleaner command

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.cpp' | sed -e 's/\/[^/]*$//' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You got it right but @John1024 wrote a shorter and cleaner command

Answer (score 1):

To simply find non-empty directories:

`$ find . \! -empty -type d`

For directories with only specific filetypes in it, I would use something like this:

`find . -name \*.cpp | while read line; do dirname "${line}" ; done | sort -u`

This finds all *.cpp files and calls `dirname` on each filename. The result is then sorted and made unique. There are definitely faster ways to do this using shell-builtins that don't require to spawn a new process for each *.cpp file. But that probably shouldn't matter for most projects.

Comment: Using shell builtins is not an option with `find`, but if you're using bash 4+, a faster solution is possible using pathname expansion with `shopt -s globstar`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what is a source file.

Notice that **some C or C++ files are *generated*** (e.g. by parser-generators like [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or `yacc`, by ad-hoc `awk` or `python` or shell scripts, by generators particular to the project, etc...), and that some included C or C++ files are not named `.h` or `.cc` (read about [X-macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)). Within [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) a significant amount of files are generated (e.g. from `*.md` machine description files, which are the authentic source files)

<sup>Most large software projects (e.g. of many millions lines of C++ or C code) have or are using some C or C++ code generators somewhere.</sup>

In the free software world, a source code is simply the *preferred form* of the code on which the developer is working.

<sup>Notice that source code might not even sit in a file; it could sit in a database, in some heap image, e.g. if the developer is interacting with a specific program to work. (Remember Smalltalk machines of the 1980s, or [Mentor structured editor](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076535) at INRIA in 1980). As another example, J.Pitrat's [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/04/caia-my-colleague/) system has its C code entirely self generated. Look also inside [Scheme48](http://www.s48.org)</sup>

Perhaps (as an approximate heuristic only) you should consider as a C++ source file any file named `.h` or  `.cc` or `.cpp` or `.cxx` or perhaps `.def` or `.inc` or `.tcc` which does not contain the `GENERATED FILE` words (usually inside some comments).

To understand what are the generated files you should dive into the build procedure (described by `Makefile`, `CMake*`, `Makefile.am` with `autoconf` etc etc...). **There is no fool-proof way of detecting or guessing generated *C++* files**; so you won't be able to reliably automate their detection.

At last, bootstrapped languages have often a (version control) repository which contain some generated files. Ocaml has a [`boot/`  subdirectory](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/boot), and [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) has a `melt/generated/` directory (containing C++ files needed to regenerate MELT in C++ form from `*.melt` source code files).

I would suggest to use the project version control [*repository*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repository_%28revision_control%29) and get the non-empty directories there. Details depend upon the [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) tool (e.g. [git](http://git-scm.com/), or `svn`, or `hg`, etc...). You should **use some version control** (or *revision control*) **tool**. I recommend `git`

Comment: Good info, but you may be overthinking this: I don't think the OP was looking for a _generic_ way to detect [C++] source files. The answer they accepted suggests that all that was needed was a way to find directories containing files with particular suffixes of interest.

Comment: Then I believe that my last paragraph is relevant. The OP should use a version control tool.